# Objective-c & php/mysql : login auth & requests

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication

I'm developing an iphone app and I need to implement a 'safe' login system.

When the users writes his credentials, using a httprequest, phpmysql responds if authentification is correct or not.

But.. Do I have to send the credentials for every request after the login? For example: When I'm logged in, if I wanna get my profile info, should I send my credentials again?

I thought to implement a 'token' system, when an user logs in the server responds with a 'token' wich could be used for every request but... What if someone 'intercepts' this token? He could make petitions using this token like if he was the other user..

Hope I could explain what I'm trying to do (not using ssl)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using http, then sending the credentials can be intercepted and all bets are off from then on, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encrypt the credentials before you transmit them using AES or a SHA512 hash.  This goes for using the token as well if you go that route.  Definitely use SSL.

Comment: I'm already using aes to encrypt the credentials. So creating the token/session when the user login and then use this session/token for every request is the best way to do it?

Comment: That would be a good way to do it.  Make sure to expire the token say after 24hr (or shorter) depending on your use case and prompt for re-authentication.

Comment: But its an iphone social app, I can't ask for re-auth every day, people wont like it. Is it any hard to implement ssl? Because, encrypting + ssl would be perfect, right? Thanks!

Comment: Store the encrypted credentials and re-authenticate silently when the token expires.  Only prompt for login when re-authentication fails.

Comment: Ok! and last question.. how should I manage the sql connections? Do I have to start a session in php? or just check if the token created when the users logs in is registered, then get the user id and go on with that in every request?

Comment: I would pass the token in the header for all web requests that way you can verify it is valid before proceeding with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You must use SSL/TLS (read: https) if you don't want someone to sniff your clear text credentials, whether it be token or any other credentials.